# How do rsa key fobs work?

Tags: authentication, rsa

Could anyone explain to me in simple programmatic terms how these RSA key dongles work? I know Blizzard has them for WoW and paypal as well as some of the trading sites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

The fob has a clock and a serial number that is used as a seed for a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRNG). When you hit the "show me a code" button, the fob displays a number that is the product of that timestamp and the serial number run through the PRNG. The server knows your fob's serial number and time, and does the same operation. If your codes match, you're authenticated.

You can calculate the previous/next N values on the server end to account for clock skew.

Comment: PRNG = pseudorandom number generator

Comment: The PayPal fob uses one of the digits for synchronization, giving the server another way of compensating for clock skew.

Comment: thanks. I thought of that, then added a link; your comment beat me to the punch, though. :)

Comment: The same method is used by British Energy on their remote-working key fobs for secure data.

Comment: I turned it into a wiki - feel free to edit the answer directly to include your comments.

Comment: Hmmm, nope... not a Wiki as far as I can see.

Comment: From a practical perspective, implementing this exchange between a client/server communication (where every message contains said 1-time token) seems to be as simple as: for every exchange made, fetch next seeded random(). Now the trick is how to persist this (if at all). Should time + seed be stored in a db? Should it be renegotiated on reconnect? if stored, should it be encrypted? Is this implementation over engineering if executed over a SSL connection?

Answer (score 3):

Programmatic terms aren't necessary. Just imagine two pieces of hardware (your dongle and something at the company) that generate the same numbers at the same regularly scheduled intervals.  It would be virtually impossible to guess what the number is due to some proprietary algorithms, so if the number you type in (or is automatically sent by the dongle) matches the number at the server, your identity is validated.

At least with the dongle I have, you also have to supply a pin known only by you and the server. So, in order to be authenticated you need both something physical and something in your head. That combination is pretty hard to fake. Even if someone gets the dongle, unless they know your pin it's worthless. And if they know your pin, that information is worthless without the dongle.

Answer (score 1):

[Security Now! episode 103](http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-103.htm) talks about how they work. (That link is to the show notes, but there's a link at the top of the page to the audio podcast.)

Basically, the key fob is synchronized with a server and they're both seeded to generate the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers.  The server knows it's you if you input the right number at the right time.